# How to add title to the checkboxselection model by removing the selectall checkbox in the header in Extjs

Tags: extjs

I have created a checkbox column :

```
var checkBoxSelectionModel = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
      mode : 'SIMPLE',
      checkOnly:true,
      showHeaderCheckbox: false
);
```

Comment: I want to add a title to this column

Answer (score 0):

You can use `headerText` to set the header text of the column, you will probably need to use `headerWidth` to increase the width of the header.

see the [working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2vef)

Comment: headerWidth is working. But headerText is not setting the text

Comment: getHeaderConfig: function() {
            return Ext.apply(this, {
                width: 100,
                header: 'Select'
            });
            }, I tried to override the method. But it is also failing. Is there any other way..?

Comment: Which version of extjs you are using?

Comment: Using Ext js 3, I guess. I'm reviewing the code written by someone. I'm very new to Ext js